# How to let the user try to guess the correct answer in my react flashcard app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hey if anybody could help me with the next step in my project, Id really appreciate it. its a very simple react flashcard app that takes 10 questions from a trivia api and displays all 10 of them at once to the screen, each card with the question and answer choices, and when the user clicks each card, the card does a simple flip animation that shows the correct answer on the back. my next challenge is to have the user attempt to get the question right by clicking on one of the answer choices and if they are wrong, it will say they are wrong until they get it right it will then flip as it did before to show the right answer. basically I just want to learn how I can make it a little bit more interactive for the user.

my app.js file maps over the dictionary objects from my api and turns them into props. Here is the code in that file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import FlashcardList from "./FlashcardList"
import './app.css'
import axios from 'axios' // makes importing from api easy

export default function App() {
const [flashcards, setFlashcards] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
    .then(res => {
        setFlashcards(res.data.results.map((questionItem, index) => { // mapping over api to get objects "questionItem" and the index of each one
            const answer = decodeString(questionItem.correct_answer) // setting the correct_answer objects from api to answer
            const options = [
                ...questionItem.incorrect_answers.map(a => decodeString(a)), answer // spreading incorrect_answers objects into an array with answer at the back to set all of them into options
            ]
            return {
                id: `&{index}-${Date.now()}`, // sets the id to the index from the api and the exact time to make sure its always unique
                question: decodeString(questionItem.question), // setting question objects from api to question
                answer: answer, // already defined above
                options: options.sort(() => Math.random() - .5) // sorting all the options randomly
            }
        }))
    })
}, [])

function decodeString(str) {
    const textArea = document.createElement('textarea')
    textArea.innerHTML= str
    return textArea.value // function brings all of our objects into this new element and decodes all of the encoded html
}
return (
    <div className="container">
        <FlashcardList flashcards={flashcards} />
    </div>
)
```

}

my flashcard.js file recieves the props from the app.js file and builds the front and back of the card, creates a useState to make the card flip, and a useState to calculate the height for each card. this is the code on the flashcard.js file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export default function Flashcard({ flashcard }) {     // recieving flashcard prop 
from our mapping in flashcardlist.js, each w a unique id

const [flip, setFlip] = useState(false)
const [height, setHeight] = useState('initial') //sets the state for our initial height to be replaced by the max height

const frontEl = useRef() // lets us have a reference from the front and back through every rerendering of them
const backEl = useRef()

function setMaxHeight() {
    const frontHeight = frontEl.current.getBoundingClientRect().height //gives us dimensions of the rectangle but we only need the height
    const backHeight = backEl.current.getBoundingClientRect().height
    setHeight(Math.max(frontHeight, backHeight, 100)) // sets the height (setHeight) to the maximum height of front or back but the minimum is 100px
}

useEffect(setMaxHeight, [flashcard.question, flashcard.answer, flashcard.options]) //anytime any of these change then the setMaxHeight will change
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', setMaxHeight) //everytime we resize our browser, it sets the max height again
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', setMaxHeight) //removes the eventlistener when component destroys itself
  }, [])


  return (
<div 
    className={`card ${flip ? 'flip' : ''}`} // if flip is true classname will be card and flip, if flip isnt true it will just be card
    style={{ height: height }} //setting height to the variable height

    onClick={() => setFlip(!flip)} // click changes it from flip to non flip
>
    <div className='front' ref={frontEl}>
        {flashcard.question}
        <div className='flashcard-options'>
            {flashcard.options.map(option => {
                return <div className='flashcard-option'>{option}</div>
            })}
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div className='back' ref={backEl}>{flashcard.answer}</div>
</div>
 )
}
// setting the front to show the question and the answers by looping through the options to make them each an option with a class name to style
// back shows the answer
```

my flashcardList.js file takes in the flashcards props from app.js and gives them each a unique id before passing it to flashcard.js to format the cards. here is that code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Flashcard from './Flashcard'

export default function FLashcardList({ flashcards }) {
  // taking in the flashcards as destructured props so we dont have to make a props. variable
  return (

// card-grid is a container so we can put all the cards in a grid to ensure they change in size proportionally to the size of the window //
<div className='card-grid'> 

  {flashcards.map(flashcard => { // loops through the flashcards api and maps each one to flashcard

      return <Flashcard flashcard={flashcard} key={flashcard.id} /> // each flashcard is then passed down to the "Flashcard.js" component we created returned w a unique id
  })}
</div>
  )
}
```

and then i have a app.css file that handles the complications of making the flip animation:

```
body {
background-color: #c8d0d2;
margin: 0;
}

.container {
max-width: 900px;
margin: 1rem 2rem;
}

.card-grid {
display: grid;
align-items: center;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr)); /* sets the cards to 
dynamically fit the page no matter how big it gets and to 200px minimum each card*/
gap: 1rem;
}

.card {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
position: relative;
border-radius: .25rem;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
background-color: white;
transform-style: preserve-3d; /* to preserve our 3d elements so the card actually 
flips to the back instead of just rotating the front 180 deg */
/* height: 150px; /* this will be changed eventually so the height is automatically 
set by the size of the content text */
transition: 150ms; /* so we can see the flip animation by slowing it down */ 
cursor: pointer;
transform:perspective(1000px) /* to make the flip seem a little more 3d, less flat 
*/rotateY(var(--rotate-y, 0)) /* card will flip  to whatever we set the rotate-y variable in .card.flip */
translateY(var(--translate-y, 0));

}

.card:hover {
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6); /* makes the outline darker when hover */
--translate-y: -2px; /* moves the card up when hover */

}

.card.flip {
--rotate-y: 180deg;
}

.card .front {
left: 0;
}

.card .front,
.card .back {
position: absolute; /* so the front and back dont offset eachother */
padding: 1rem;
backface-visibility: hidden; /* makes it so anything facing backwards is hidden so 
the back of the card isnt showing on the front and the front isn't showing when the 
card is flipped to the back */ 
}

.card .back {
transform: rotateY(180deg); /* needs to be rotated because it's on the back so it 
will be flipped to the front and made right side up when flipped */
}

.flashcard-options {
margin-top: .5rem;

}

.flashcard-option {
margin-top: .25rem;
color: #555;
font-size: .75rem;
}

.flashcard-option:first-child {
margin-top: 0;
}
```

I'm a beginner and i appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried already on your own for this? Is there a specific issue you have with your implementation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're having difficulty with, since it seems your code is set up pretty close to what you want (I haven't run it or anything), but seems like you just want to add a click event to where you're listing your options.

```
<div className='flashcard-options'>
  {flashcard.options.map(option => {
       return <div onClick={() => handleUserPicksAnswer(option)} className='flashcard-option'>{option}</div>
  })}
</div>
```

From there just write the logic for the trivia game inside `handleUserPicksAnswer`. Something similar to the following.

```
function Flashcard(props) {
     // other stuff
    const [incorrect, setIncorrect] = useState(0)
    const [flip, setFlip] = useState(false)
    const handleUserPicksAnswer = (answer) => {
        if(answer.is_correct) {
           // display correct prompt - whatever you want
           return
        } 
        if(incorrect + 1 === MAX_TRIES) {
             setFlip(true)
        }
        setIncorrect(incorrect + 1)
    }
    return <div>
        {// other stuff }
        <div className='flashcard-options'>
           {flashcard.options.map(option => {
               return <div onClick={() => handleUserPicksAnswer(option)} 
                           className='flashcard-option'
               >{option}</div>
            })}
          </div>
</div>
    </div>
}
```

Something approximate to that.